# Скачать каталог с удаленного сервера

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Есть облачный сервер, доступ к нему осуществляется через консоль на сайте хостинга. На сервере стоит ubuntu 18.04. Как я могу скачать каталог оттуда к себе на компьютер?

Comment: А что случилось с прямым ssh-доступом?

Comment: Есть ли доступ по ssh к серверу?

Comment: Если нет ssh. Можно создать тарбол и потом разрезать его на Н частей и при помощи `cat` потихоньку перекидывать куски на свою машину и потом уже сшить все обратно. Если виртуалка имеет доступ в интернет - отправте тарбол по почте или фтп или другой сервер где есть ssh демон. Или если есть рут права установите openssh-server

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь командой `pscp` с опцией `-r` (что значит копировать рекурсивно):

```
pscp -r user@your.server.com:/path/to/folder/on/server c:\path\to\folder\on\local\
```

Comment: Формулировка вопроса неявно намекает, что scp возможно не сможет подключиться к серверу

Comment: Я не уловил этого намека. Если нет ssh доступа, то ответ не годится.

Comment: не знаю, что подразумевается под ssh доступом, но через программу putty с меткой ssh я присоединился к серверу, однако все равно вводил логин и пароль. Видимо, доступ по ssh всее таки есть и ваша команда мне подойдет, однако, как мне правильно прописать путь на своей машине? Какой путь я бы не писал, пишет, что не существует такой директории.

Comment: Поправил для windows.

Comment: @RomanKonoval выдает следующую ошибку `security violation: remote host attempted to write to a '.' or '..' path!`
в общем, она решилась добавлением `;` в конец строки, в окне пошел процесс загрузки файлов, но в конечной папке все равно пусто.